# Git commit uses regular expressions or globs?

Tags: regex, git, glob

Is it possible to use [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) in, e.g., `git commit ".*my_file.*"` ?

I tried, and it seems to only interpret these as [globs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29).  I also tired a regex flag:

```
git commit -regex ".*my_file.*"`
```

Throws an error.

Does anyone know of a way to combine regular expressions with Git commands?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, globs can be used for both `git add`, and `git commit`, I just don't know whether it is possible to use regex, which would be wonderful for me.

Comment: Oh, true. I've found that syntax in Git reference; never seen it before.

Comment: Maybe you tried to add untracked files? From Git reference:

" by listing files as arguments to the commit command, in which case the commit will ignore changes staged in the index, and instead record the current content of the listed files **(which must already be known to Git);**"

Answer (score 2):

The best way I can think of to do this is using the find command.  For example, if you want only python files:

```
find -type f -regex ".*\.py$" -exec git commit {} -m "committing only and all python files" \;
```

Can anyone else think of something less unwieldy?

Answer (score 1):

Not with Git itself. Git just receives a list of files passed from the shell, so it would be up to your shell to do regular expression matching for files. I do not think bash can do this, but other shells may be able to.

Comment: Git also understand `-- <filepattern>`, where `<filepattern>` can be a singly-quoted string containings globs (and thus not expanded by shell); those globs can be used to select a subset of files to `add`. For example: `git add -- '*.el'` would add all `.el` files in current and nested directories: globs act on the whole name, like `-wholename` in `find`.

Comment: @coredump: That will work, but only if there is not a `.el` file in the current directory, in which case the shell will not expand the file glob pattern, instead passing a literal `*.el` to `git add`, which will then interpret it as a pattern spec.

Comment: Please have a look at this transcript: http://pastebin.com/KmejAU3i. It works, even when there is an `.el` file in current directory. Expansion is not done by the shell, because the glob is quoted.

Comment: @coredump: Yes, sorry, quoting a file glob will prevent the shell from expanding it into a list of files, in which case it will get passed as-is to `git add`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by mipadi, arguments can be generated by the shell to produce the input for `git`.

For example, `ls` can be used in combination for this. Let's say I've got a git init-ed directory with the following files:

```
.git/
my_new_project_file.py
my_older_project_file.py
some_other_file.py
```

And I want to add everything but `some_other_file.py`. To do this:

```
ls my*project*.py | xargs git add
```

Checking my `git status` will show that both `my_new_project_file.py` and `my_older_project_file.py` have been staged, while `some_other_file.py` has been ignored.

*n.b.* `ls` doesn't support regex; just globbing.

Comment: That's cool, but git already supports globbing:   `git add "my*project*.py"` does the same

Comment: `ls` does neither; it is the shell which expands the globs before `ls` runs. Anyway, [don't use `ls` in scripts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs); see also [useless use of `ls`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#ls)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Candic3, `git` supports globs:

```sh
git add *my_file*
```

Comment: Without quotes, it will be the shell that most likely interprets the glob in your example.

Answer (score -1):

The answers seem to indicate this is not possible with git alone, but requires a shell.

This seems not correct these days. This works for me in zsh:

```
git -C path/to/repo checkout '**package-lock.json'
```

In zsh shell, the content inside the quotes will not be expanded, it is passed along as-is, so `git` must be interpreting the glob.

I'd expect this to be cross-platform.